# Moving Colored Cell

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to loop a cell (that is colored lets say red) to move back and forth from lets say `A1` to `I1`?

I tried simply recording it, but it moves too fast and while the macro is running i cannot do anything else, like write...

Comment: what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: I want to create a game in which you have a cell that you control, and moving objects that you need to avoid, is it possible?

Comment: moving a cell from A to I is easy. Let's say a red cell moves from A to B and to C in 1 second. This 1 second can be customized. But what do you want to do in this 1 second?

Comment: I want it just to move. Heres an example [link](http://www.doublegames.com/images/screenshots/chicken-cross-the-road_3_big.jpg). The chicken is my cell that i control, and the car's in this case are the cell that i want to move back and forth.

Comment: See the answer that I posted. is that what you are trying?

Answer (score 2):

Here is  basic demonstration of how to move your "Cars", The button is linked to `StartGame`. File can be downloaded [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1pjkrzzpix2a7l/Car%20Example.xlsm?dl=0)

Paste this code in a module

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range

Sub StartGame()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    i = 1: j = 1: k = 1

    MoveCar1
End Sub

Sub MoveCar1()
    With ws
        Set r = .Cells(6, i)

        r.Cut
        r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        i = i + 1
    End With

    Wait 1

    MoveCar2
End Sub

Sub MoveCar2()
    With ws
        Set r = .Cells(6, i)

        r.Cut
        r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        i = i + 1

        Set r = .Cells(8, j)

        r.Cut
        r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        j = j + 1
    End With

    Wait 1

    MoveCar3
End Sub

Sub MoveCar3()
    With ws
        Set r = .Cells(6, i)
        r.Cut
        r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        i = i + 1

        Set r = .Cells(8, j)
        r.Cut
        r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        j = j + 1

        Set r = .Cells(10, k)
        r.Cut
        r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        k = k + 1
    End With

    Wait 1

    MoveAllCars
End Sub

Sub MoveAllCars()
    For l = 1 To 8
        With ws
            If i < 9 Then
                Set r = .Cells(6, i)
                r.Cut
                r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                i = i + 1
            End If

            If j < 9 Then
                Set r = .Cells(8, j)
                r.Cut
                r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                j = j + 1
            End If

            If k < 9 Then
                Set r = .Cells(10, k)
                r.Cut
                r.Offset(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                k = k + 1
            End If

            Wait 1

            If i > 8 And j > 8 And k > 8 Then Exit For
        End With
    Next l
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

**Screenshots**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It can be done but it is very complex. Excel is actually not meant for this. Why don't you try making it in VB.Net?

Comment: It's great, thanks! Is it possible to that it would go back too? And loop it?

Comment: Yup reverse the loop :) Give it a try. If you get stuck post the code

Comment: I have updated the post. Refresh the page. Now understand the logic how the cars are reaching Col I. Simply use the logic to go back...

Comment: This is cool, thank you very much :) I am pretty new to vba. Do you mean to write another code, that will bring them back?

Comment: But when they will go back, how to launch the first command that is moving them forth?

Comment: Think ;) Understand the logic how the code is working. What is the initial value of i,j and k? What do they represent? what would be their value when all cars reach Col I... Spend some time with it. It is pretty simple actually :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
Sub MyGame()
   Dim A As Range, I As Range, T As Date
   Dim T30 As Date
   Set A = Range("A1")
   Set I = Range("I1")
   A.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
   T = Now
   T30 = T + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
   While Now < T30
      DoEvents
      If A.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
         A.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
         I.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      Else
         A.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
         I.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
      End If
   Wend
End Sub
```

It will color cell **A1** red and then move that color back and forth between **A1** and **I1** for about 10 seconds.

Comment: Yeah.. even i thought of coloring the cell but went against the idea because if I want to replace the colored cell with a car shape then I will get stuck. So working with the actual object. But none the less ++